# Constante no definida WSDL_CACHE_DISK

Tags: soap, symfony2, symfony

¿Como se puede resolver el siguiente error en `Symfony 2.8` con `Soap`?

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                      
Notice: Use of undefined constant WSDL_CACHE_DISK - assumed 'WSDL_CACHE_DISK'
```

Me ocurre cuando intento usar comandos como por ejemplo: `php app/console cache:clear` u otros comandos por consola.

Si me pueden orientar, como resolverlo. Probé limpiar manualmente la cache, cerrar y abrir la consola y el ide.
Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes tenes instalada y habilitada la `php5-soap`

```
apt-get install php5-soap
```

O si es PHP 7

```
 apt-get install php7.0-soap
```

Si tu Sistema Operativo es windows debes de editar el archivo `php.ini` y quitar el `;extension=php_soap.dll` => `extension=php_soap.dll`